# Install Supervisor on macOs via brew but no config file in /etc?

Tags: laravel, supervisord

Has anyone installed `supervisor` on macOs and asked me this question. Currently I install `supervisor` for macOs:

```
brew install supervisor
```

According to the instructions I went to `/etc/` -> No directory `supervisor/conf.d`.....

And I also access under `/usr/local/etc/` -> there is only one file which is : `supervisord.conf`.

So I can't configure like below:

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
directory=/path/to/your/project
command=sendmail.sh
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=forge
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/path/to/your/project/logs/worker.log
```

I have installed something missing or wrong. Please help me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `/opt/homebrew/etc/supervisor.d` and create your conf file (here **laravel-worker.conf**)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is where the configuration files must be placed on my machine